# Android Listview with Images and Wakefull BroadCastReceiver and Service Issue

Tags: android, image, android-listview, android-service, android-broadcast

I have and Activity Which looks like this

```
listData = new ArrayList<OveriewMessageModal>(); 
    try {
        ChatMsgsDao cm = new ChatMsgsDao(this);
        cm.openReadOnly();
        listData = cm.getApplicationOverviewMessages();
        cm.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TRACE_ID, "Error ", e);
    }

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_msg);

    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, listData);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter Code

```
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<OveriewMessageModal> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView applicationId = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.applicationId); // applicationid
    TextView userInfoId = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.userInfoId); // userInfoId
    TextView applicationoruser = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.applicationoruser); // applicationoruser
    TextView message = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.message); // message
    TextView messageCount = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.messagecount); // message
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    OveriewMessageModal omm = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    applicationId.setText(omm.getApplicationId()+"");
    userInfoId.setText(omm.getUserInfoId()+"");
    applicationoruser.setText(appusername);
    message.setText(dm1.getMsgTitle());
    messageCount.setText(omm.getMessageCount()+"");

    try {
        duration.setText(CommonUtility.getDateInformationForListView(omm.getMessageReceivedTime()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        duration.setText(omm.getMessageReceivedTime());
    }

    if(photoPath.equalsIgnoreCase("") && omm.getIsServerIconChanged() == 0) {
        thumb_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
    } else {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(omm, thumb_image);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

BroadCast Receviver Code

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("GCM_Broadcast", "...... .. .. GcmBroadcastReceiver called ......  ..... ......");
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

I want when i receive the new message in Service with my app running on listview. My Listview should get Updated?. Also There is an background aysnctask that through webservices check for image changes if there then it is download, but do i update it in my running listview. Also If there is a data change in object of listview, it should be reflected in the running listview

Please help?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I receive my messages in service, which is stored in database and sends notification to mobile. This Notification activates the activity with listview till noiw its find. Now Listview activity is running and I receive message in service and stored in database. but not displayed in my listview. Also this listview contains images, which are downloaded in bachground. So to relect the new images, I need to restart my app. Please suggest the solution for the same